# What is independence number alpha of cycle graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any formula to find the independence number of a cycle graph with n vertices.
What is the independence number of cycle graph with 5 vertices.

Answer (score 3):

$\alpha(C_n) = \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor $

Hint: Consider the two cases where $n$ is odd and even to prove this.